# How to find out the UTC offset of my current location in Qt 5.1?

Tags: qt, utc, timezone-offset, qdatetime

I had to write a function returning the offset from UTC of my current location. To my greatest surprize, the following code returned 0:

```
const QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
return now.toUTC().secsTo(now) / 60;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not as easy as it looks, because QDateTime::secsTo calculates offset after converting to UTC. I found an answer [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Incorrect-utcOffset-from-QDateTime-currentDateTimeUtc/td-p/2098465%22here%22), but I didn't really like the conversion to string and back. So my solution is:

```
const QDateTime dateTime1 = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
const QDateTime dateTime2 = QDateTime(dateTime1.date(), dateTime1.time(), Qt::UTC);
return dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int getTimezoneOffsetMinutes()
{
    const QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    return now.timeZone().offsetFromUtc(now) / 60;
}
```